# Charting libraries in PHP output to SVG or Canvas?

Tags: php, charts, graph, canvas, svg

I'm looking for a charting library written in PHP that outputs to SVG (or Canvas), possibly for integration into an ExtJS project. I like the look of http://pchart.sourceforge.net/index.php but it does bitmap output and is GPL licensed, which will probably be a show-stopper since the project is an internal commercial project.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may have a look at http://www.pchart.net/license to purchase a license matching your use case.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be quite what you're looking for, but there's a PHP Object wrapper for Google Charts:

http://code.google.com/p/gchartphp/

Do you need PHP to generate the actual image via the GD library?

Answer (score 1):

(I know this is an old thread but thought I'd add my two cents.) My understanding of the GPL when it applies to libraries is that you can develop an application that uses the libraries commercially but if you make any customisations to the library in the process you are required to make the source code available for just those customisations. You must also preserve the GPL information with the library if you distribute your application and bundle the library with it. I'm about to give SVGGraph a go http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php.

Comment: A library can be distributed under either the GPL or the LGPL, in OP's library is being distributed under the GPL.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend a PHP + Flotr solution http://solutoire.com/flotr/

You can pass JSON as output from PHP to Flotr, which is a JavaScript library that will draw the chart for you.  It's incredibly fast, and it works very well, especially when you need to update your chart on the fly with modifications to your metrics.

Because Flotr is a JS library, all you have to do after your page is loaded is update it on the client-side or run a quick Ajax request back to the server for additional data points.

Here's an example of Flotr pulling JSON data on-the-fly using ajax: http://www.solutoire.com/experiments/flotr/examples/json-data.html

While I prefer Flotr + PHP, there's also a full-featured charting library for PHP that works in roughly the same way, but it's wrapped up as one complete library (JS + PHP): http://phpchart.net

Answer (score 0):

It's not Canvas based but if you find yourself stuck, i recommend [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/)

Answer (score 0):

ezComponents' [Graph component](http://zetacomponents.org/documentation/trunk/Graph/tutorial.html) can render into different formats, including svg.